# Rearrangement of absolutely convergent series: proof verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

There is a theorem saying that if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_j$ converges absolutely, then any rearrangement $\{x_{\pi(j)}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of the original series $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ also converges ($\pi:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$).

The proof I see in a book uses the fact that $x_j=\max(x_j,0)-\max(-x_j,0)$, so the original convergent series can be split into two convergent series.

I am wondering 1) whether this step is really needed in the proof, 2) can not we make the theorem stronger ans say that any rearrangement gives us not only convergent but absolutely convergent series?

My attempt:

1. From absolute convergence of the original series follows that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|=s$ and $\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2} >0 \exists N_1, \forall n \ge N_1, |s_n-s|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ($s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|$).
2. From absolute convergence and Cauchy condition for convergent numerical sequences follows that $\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2}>0,\exists N_2, \forall m,n \ge N_2, |s_n-s_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$
3. $N_3 = \max(N_1,N_2)$, we find $N_4$ such that $\{j\}_{j=0}^{N_3} \subset \{\pi(j)\}_{j=0}^{N_4}$.
4. We consider $n \ge N_4$, $|s-\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{\pi(j)}||=|s-\sum_{j=1}^{N_3}|x_j|-\sum_{\pi(j) \in \{\pi(j)\}_{j=0}^{n} \setminus \{j\}_{j=0}^{N_3}} |x_{\pi(j)}|| \le |s-\sum_{j=1}^{N_3}|x_j||+\sum_{\pi(j) \in \{\pi(j)\}_{j=0}^{n} \setminus \{j\}_{j=0}^{N_3}} |x_{\pi(j)}| \le |s-\sum_{j=1}^{N_3}|x_j|| + \sum_{j=N_3+1}^{\max(\{\pi(j)\}_{j=0}^{n})} |x_j| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Have I proved what I needed to prove?

Comment: Wouldn't it be way easier, shorter and simpler to write $\;\Bbb N\;$ instead of the cumbersome $\;[1,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z\;$ ? Or at least simply $\;\Bbb Z_+\;$ ?